# Updating/deleting mongoose object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose Schema with fields:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        maxlength: 60,
        required:true
    },
    usedIn:Object
})
```

Where usedAt is an object with projectId as *key* and user role as *value*. It looks like that:

```
usedIn:{'563d2733135ad2542dc5bdb6':'manager','563d2733135ad2542dc5bdb7':'worker'}
```

This approach allows me us easily access user's role by projectId and make sure user has unique role in project.

If user had no role in this project it works perfect, but as soon as I need to update/remove user's role problems beginning. I.e. I can't update property of usedIn[projectId], but I'm sure I give valid object to be saved, I got no errors during saving, but property was not updated. Same with deleting. I can't delete property.
I.m using

```
    if(role!='none')
        user.usedIn[projectId] = role;
    else
        user.usedIn[projectId] = undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer while was writing this question :)
To update/delete properties at 'Object' I had to use this way:

```
    if(role!='none')
        user.set('usedIn.'+projectId,role);
    else
        user.set('usedIn.'+projectId,undefined);
```

Now it works great with creating/updating/removing properties. If someone can explain why this way worked - you are welcome :)